# IDL: Using a 64bit .save file with a 32 bit virtual machine

Tags: idl-programming-language

If I compile a .save file in a 64 bit IDL version, will it work with the 32 bit IDL virtual machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 32-bit or 64-bit should not matter. The only problem is the IDL version. From the help:

> Note: Files containing IDL routines and system variables can only be restored by versions of IDL that share the same internal code representation. Since the internal code representation changes regularly, you should always archive the IDL language source files (.pro files) for routines you are placing in IDL SAVE files so you can recompile the code when a new version of IDL is released.